# Check if NSString is valid number - whole or decimal number

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, numbers, nscharacterset

I have an iOS app with a `UITextField` that allows the user to enter a number in. How can I ensure that the value the user types in is a valid number (either whole or decimal). Here is what I have tried, but for some reason it won't work for decimal numbers:

```
NSCharacterSet *notDigits = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];

if ([numString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:notDigits].location == NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"valid number");
}

else {
    NSLog(@"invalid number");
}
```

If I enter a decimal number such as 435.634, the above code returns "invalid number" in the console log. I don't understand why this isn't working as I am using `decimalDigitCharacterSet`?

Comment: Use `NSNumberFormatter` so it properly deals with locale specific numbers.

Comment: The `decimalDigitCharacterSet` set contains digits, not any punctuation.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff - another option is to present the user with a number keypad. No need to worry about anything else then - https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=numeric

Comment: @SamB The user could still paste a non number value into the text field though.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, I ended up using NSNumber's ```numberFromString``` method in conjunction with a simple ```NSNumberFormatter``` to solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @rmaddy for helping me out, here is the solution I am using in case anyone is interested:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSNumber *myNumber = [formatter numberFromString:inputNumString];

if (myNumber != nil) {
    NSLog(@"valid number");
}

else {
    NSLog(@"invalid number");
}
```

This will work even if the number is whole or decimal. It also works with different locale decimal characters such as `,`